# I get an incorrect position from .get_rect()?

Tags: python, click, pygame, mouse

I'm currently working on a school project where I'm making a "hexcells" similar game in pygame and now I'm trying to blit an a new image if the user has clicked a current image. It will blit an image in the top left area, if clicked in the top left area, but not if I click any of the existing images. I told the program to print the coordinates from the images with help of the .get_rect() function, but it remains the same whereever I click and the coordinates aren't even where a image is. Can someone help me understand how this works and help me blit the new images on top of the existing images? Code below is not the entire document, however there is so much garbage/trash/unused code so I'd thought I spare you the time of looking at irrelevant code. Also sorry if the formatting is wrong or the information isn't enough, I tried my best.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *


#Magic numbers
fps = 30
winW = 640
winH = 480
boxSize = 40
gapSize = 75
boardW = 3
boardH = 3
xMargin = int((winW - (boardW * (boxSize + gapSize))) / 2)
yMargin = int((winW - (boardW * (boxSize + gapSize))) / 2)
#Lil bit o' color R G B
NAVYBLUE = ( 60,  60, 100)
correctCords = [[175,275,375],[375,275,175]]
bgColor = NAVYBLUE

unC = pygame.image.load("unC.png")
cor = pygame.image.load("correct.png")
inc = pygame.image.load("wrong.png")
correct = "Correct"
inCorrect = "Incorrect"

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((winW, winH))
    mousex = 0 #stores x-coordinate of mouse event
    mousey = 0 #stores y-coordinate of mouse event
    pygame.display.set_caption("Branches")

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(bgColor)
    gridGame(inCorrect, correct,gapSize,xMargin,yMargin,boxSize)

while True:
    mouseClicked = False


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            mousex,mousey = event.pos
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mousex, mousey = event.pos
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            mouseClicked = True
            unCa = unC.get_rect()
            corA = cor.get_rect()
            print unCa
            print corA
            print pos
            if unCa.collidepoint(pos):
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(cor,(mousey,mousex))

            """lada = unC.get_rect()
            lada = 
            if mousex and mousey == lada:
                for x in correctCords:
                    for y in x:
                        for z in x:
                            if mousey and mousex == z and y:

                                DISPLAYSURF.blit(cor,(mousey,mousex))
            print lada"""



    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(fps)


def gridGame(inCorrect, correct,gapSize,xMargin,yMargin,boxSize):
grid = []
cordX = []
cordY = []
correctRecs = []
#cordinates = []
#cordinates.append([])
#cordinates.append([])
#cordinates.append([])
#this is basically getBoard() all over again
#This part will arrange the actual backend grid
for row in range(3):
    grid.append([])
    #cordinates[0].append(gapSize+(row+1)*100)
    #cordinates[1].append(gapSize+(row+1)*100)
    #cordinates[2].append(gapSize+(row+1)*100)
    for column in range(3):
        grid[row].append(inCorrect)


for row in range(3):
    cordX.append([])
    for column in range(3):
        cordX[row].append(gapSize+(row+1)*100)

for row in range(3):
    cordY.append([])
    for column in range(3):
        cordY[row].append(gapSize+(column+1)*100)
#print cordX[0][0], cordY[0][0]



grid[0][2] = correct
grid[1][1] = correct
grid[2][0] = correct
#Y-AXEL SKRIVS FoRST ([Y][X])

#print cordinates[2][1]
DISPLAYSURF.blit(cor,(100,100)) 



#Let's draw it as well
for row in range(3):
    for column in range(3):
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(unC,(gapSize+(row+1)*100,gapSize+(column+1)*100))
main()
```

Also real sorry about the horrible variable naming and occasional swedish comments.

Answer (score 1):

`unCa = unC.get_rect()` gives you only image size - so use it only once at start (before `while True`) - and later use the same `unCa` all the time to keep image position and change it.

btw: better use more readable names - like `unC_rect`

ie.

```
 # move 10 pixel to the right
 unC_rect.x += 10

 # set new position
 unC_rect.x = 10

 unC_rect.right = 100

 unC_rect.topleft = (10, 200)

 unC_rect.center = (10, 200)

 # center on screen
 unC_rect.center = DISPLAYSURF.get_rect().center
```

etc.

And then use this `rect` to blit image

```
 blit(unC, unC_rect)
```

and check collision with other `rect`

```
 if unC_rect.colliderect(other_rect):
```

or with point - like mouse position

```
 elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
     if unC_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
         hover = True

 # shorter

 elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
     hover = unC_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
```

Comment: This certainly helps, however will this work when I need about 9 instances of the same image in different locations?

Comment: create list with 9 instances of `rect` and then use `unC_rect[0]`, `unC_rect[1]`, etc.